# Spring batch usage or how to launch Jobs within a Job

Tags: spring-batch, transactional

**TL;DR**: How should one create Spring Batch Jobs using Spring Batch Job?
Transaction boundaries seem to be the problem. This seems to be a
classic question but here it goes again:

I have following use case: I need to poll a FTP server and store found
XML files as a blob in database. XML has 0...N entries of interest I
need to send to the external Web Service and store the
response. Responses can be non-retryable or retryable and I need to
store each request and their responses for auditing purposes.

The domain/JPA model is as follows: Batch (contains XML blob) contains
0-N BatchRow objects. BatchRow contains data to be sent to the web
service and it also contains 1...N BatchRowHistory objects holding status
information about web service calls.

I was asked to implement this using Spring Batch (Spring Integration
could've been other possibility since this case of integration). Now
I've struggled with different approaches and I find this task much
more complex and therefore difficult as it IMHO should be.

I've split the tasks to following jobs:

**Job1**:

- Step11: Fetch file and store to the database as a blob.
- Step12: Split XML to entries and store those entries to db.
- **Step13**: Create Job2 and launch it for each entry stored in
       Step12. Mark Job2 created flag up in the domain model
       database for entries.

**Job2**:

- Step21: Call web service for each entry and store result to db. Retry and
       skip logic dwells here. Job2 types need possibly manual restarting etc.

The logic behind this structure is that Job1 is run periodically
scheduled (once a minute or so). Job2 is run whenever there are
those Jobs and they have either succeeded or their retry limit is up
and they have failed. Domain model stores basically only results and
Spring Batch is responsible for running the show. Manual relaunches
etc can be handled via Spring Batch Admin (at least I hope so). Also
Job2 has the BatchRow's id in the JobParameters map so it can be
viewed in Spring Batch Admin.

**Question 1**: *Does this job structure make sense?* I.e. creating new
Spring Batch Jobs for each row in db, it kind of seems to defeat the
purpose and re-invent the wheel at some level?

**Question 2**: *How do I create those Job2 entries in Step13?*

I got first problems with transaction and JobRepository but succeeded
to launch few jobs with following setup:

```
<batch:step id="Step13" parent="stepParent">
 <batch:tasklet>
   <batch:transaction-attributes propagation="NEVER"/>
   <batch:chunk reader="rowsWithoutJobReader" processor="batchJobCreator" writer="itemWriter"
                commit-interval="10" />
 </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="stepParent" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean" abstract="true"/>
```

Please note that commit-interval="10" means this can create up to 10
jobs currently and that's it... because batchJobCreator calls
JobLauncher.run method and it goes swimmingly BUT itemWriter can not
write BatchRows back to the database with updated information (boolean
jobCreated flag toggled on). Obvious reason for that is the propagation.NEVER in transaction-attributes, but without it I can't create jobs with jobLauncher.

Because updates are not passed to the database, I get the same BatchRows again and
they clutter the log with:

```
org.springframework.batch.retry.RetryException: Non-skippable exception in recoverer while processing; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=1, version=0, JobParameters=[{batchRowId=71}], Job=[foo.bar]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$2.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:278)
        at org.springframework.batch.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:420)
        at org.springframework.batch.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:289)
        at org.springframework.batch.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.transform(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:287)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:190)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:74)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:293)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

That means that job has already been created in Spring Batch and it
tries to create those files again on later executions of Step13. I
could circumvent this setting the jobCreated flag to true in the
Job2/Step21 but it feels kind of kludgy and wrong to me.

**Question 3**: I had more domain object driven approach; I had Spring
Batch Jobs scanning domain tables using pretty elaborate JPQL queries
and JPAItemReaders. The problem with this approach is that this does
not use Spring Batch's finer features. The history and retry logic are
the problem. I need to code the retry logic to the JPQL queries
directly (for example, if BatchRow has more than 3 BatchRowHistory
elements it has failed and needs to be manually re-examined). *Should I
bite the bullet and continue with this approach instead of trying to
create individual Spring Batch Job for each web service call?*

Software info if needed: Spring Batch 2.1.9, Hibernate 4.1.2, Spring
3.1.2, Java 6.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the long story, Timo

**Edit 1:** 
The reason why I think I need to spawn new jobs is this:

- Loop while reader returns null OR exception is thrown
- Transaction start
- reader - processor - writer loop for the whole N rows
- Transaction end for batch size N

Each failed entry is the problem; I want manually restartable
executions (Jobs are the only ones that are restartable in the Spring
Batch Admin, right?) for each row in the batch so that I could use
Spring Batch Admin to view failed jobs (with their job parameters
which contain row ids from domain db) and restart those etc. How do I
accomplish this kind of behaviour without spawning jobs and storing
the history to the domain db?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i hate responding with questions... but i need to know something?

1) If your input files are XML, why don't you use the StaxEventItemReader on them and simply persist your entries in step 1?

2) Starting a second job from a step!!!!  i don't even know if it should works... but IMO.. it smells ;-)

Why dont you just define another step that use a JdbcCursorItemReader to read your entries and call the web services in a ItemProcessor, then write the result in the database?

Maybe i don't understand your requirement to create different jobs for every call to the web service!!!

I Did something similar to your use case and it was done using this scenario:

Job 1 :
  step 1 : read xml, process pojo->domain obj, write domain obj in DB

Job 2 :
  step 1 : read obj from db, process = call WS, write response in DB

This was simple and worked very well (including restartable and skip features)

Hope it will help

regards

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

1: I need to store the original file to the db for auditing
purposes. StaxReader can't read that file directly from the db afaik.

2: Yeah, this seems to be the problem that is not very easily done ;-)

About your structure: Job1 looks the same as mine except that job
spawning part.

Comment: Job 2 is about the same when the happy path is walked meaning when
there are no IO problems. So when the WS call succeeds, it writes
response nicely to the db. When there are problems, then nothing gets
written to the db because transaction is rolled back. 

How do you take care of retrying if you are able to write the WS call
result to the database? Skipping an element needs to be logged to the
database as well, did you manage to do that? I'm aware of
RetryListener and SkipListener interfaces, but do they enable writing
(JPA) entries back to the database?